# Using DB unit to load DEMO data

Tags: maven, dbunit

I'm using the Maven DBUnit plugin to load test data for unit tests. I'd also like to use it for loading a different set of data to a different db for demo purposes. The dbunit plugin only allows for a single execution. Should I just create a separate pom or is there some trick that I can do to make this happen. (I.e., I'd like to simply do something like mvn load-demo-data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can [execute a plugin several times](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-plugins.html#Using_the_executions_Tag) if you like it depends just on the configuration you give in the pom:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-whatever-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>execution1</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
        <configuration>
          ....
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>WhatEverGoalYouHave</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>...</phase>
      </execution>
      <execution>
        <id>execution2</id>
        <configuration>
         ....
        </configuration>
        <goals>
          <goal>WhatEverGoalYouHave</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>...</phase>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

You can also define a profile to control the execution which might the right choice for your demo data. The call you described mvn load-demo-data is not possible with maven, cause maven calls only a goal or lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

Use properties when configuring the database credentials

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>dbunit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>${dbunit.plugin.version}</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <url>${db.url}</url>
                        <driver>${db.driver}</driver>
                        <username>${db.username}</username>
                        <password>${db.password}</password>
                     </configuration>
                     ..
```

Then add a profiles section to your POM, controling the setting of these properties:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>db1</id>
        <properties>
           <db.url>jdbc:h2:target/db1;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</db.url>
           <db.driver>org.h2.Driver</db.driver>
           <db.username>user</db.username>
           <db.password>pass</db.password>
        </properties>
    <profile>
    <profile>
        <id>db2</id>
        <properties>
           <db.url>jdbc:h2:target/db2;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE</db.url>
           <db.driver>org.h2.Driver</db.driver>
           <db.username>user</db.username>
           <db.password>pass</db.password>
        </properties>
    <profile>
    ..
```

The profile cane be activated as follows to update two different databases

```
mvn -Pdb1 clean test
mvn -Pdb2 clean test
```